# Solving a linear matrix equation with respect to the maximum of the euclidian distances between rows.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, regression, matrix-equations

With $n>m$, real number matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ are shaped like:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{1,1} & \cdots  & a_{1,m} \\
 \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
 a_{n,m} & \cdots  & a_{n,m} \\
\end{array}
\right),B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 b_{m,1} & b_{m,2} \\
\end{array}
\right),C=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  \\
 c_{n,1} & c_{n,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
With $A$ and $C$ fixed, how do I find the B matrix that minimizes the expression:

$$\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max }\left(\left(c_{i,1}-\left(a_{i,1} b_{1,1}+a_{i,2} b_{2,1}+\text{...}+a_{i,m} b_{m,1}\right)\right){}^2+\left(c_{i,2}-\left(a_{i,1} b_{1,2}+a_{i,2} b_{2,2}+\text{...}+a_{i,m} b_{m,2}\right)\right){}^2\right)$$

That is the largest diagonal element of $(C-A\cdot B)\cdot (C-A\cdot B)^{\mathsf{T}}$

The rank of $A$ is $m$.

Comment: I forgot that rank of $A$ is $m$, but I don't get why infinity could be a solution. Chosen $B$ to be the null-matrix will give finite result which is better, because I need to minimize?? Do you know any analytical algorithm for this? Please give me names

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, I thought you wanted to maximize the largest diagonal element. Indeed, in the case of minimisation, $+\infty$ is not a solution.

Comment: you can easily minimize each diagonal element individually - after all, it's a convex function of elements of $B$. You can try to split the problem into a series of minimisation problems with constraints: minimize $i$-th diagonal element under the constraint that other diagonal elements are smaller. Like this you will have $n$ solvable problems  (convex minimisation with convex constraints). After that you'll need to compare the solutions. There might be more elegant ways to solve your problem.

Comment: How do I solve this easily

Comment: which problem? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Minimizing a diagonal element under the constraint that other diagonal element are smaller?